# How to write VBA code to copy the cell data based on the selection of the rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel

In the below screenshot, I would like to write a VBA code to do the following actions:

1. I will select the range of cells (using mouse or keyboard)
2. Always the cell(1,1) will be the sheet name
3. Copy the selected range of data using macro key into step 2 sheet
4. Save the sheet
5. Repeat step 1, 2, 3 until manually close the Excel

**Image:**

[image: Sample image]

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad. Work on each step (try something out, most of it can already be found if not on this site, on Google) then if you somehow can't make it work, post *specific issue*, posting the relevant code and error( if any) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it'd be something like follows:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    With Selection
        Sheets.Add.name = .Cells(1, 1)
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Sheets(.Cells(1, 1).value).Range("A1")
    End With
End Sub
```

feel free to add all necessary checks for assure error handling (e.g.: no selection made, only 1 row selected, target sheet already existent, ...) of which you may find dozens of examples around here

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the below line code? How does it works? Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Sheets(.Cells(1, 1).value).Range("A1") because am struggling to write the requirement as follows 1) macro should not allow to copy duplicate tab name & data on the selection 2) while copying the block of data in the next sheet, blank rows should be deleted if any 3) tab name should not contain any special character and not exceeding 20 characters. all these must satisfy whenever use macro key. it would be much helpful to help me out on writing the code. thanks in advance

Comment: You are welcome. Offset(nRows,nCols) shifts the referenced range (in this case by one row below); Resize(nRows,nCols) resizes it (in this case by one row less); the result of them both being to skip the first row (header, not needed). As ler this site rules 1) If my answer solved your _original_ question then please consider marking it as accepted. 2) If you have more issues then post them in a new answer along with your efforts in trying and solving them. Thank you

Comment: yes, i have wrote them myself and its working fine. Once again thanks

Comment: @LokanathK, you are welcome. you may then want to mark my answer as accepted. thank you